# How to disable Weekends in this calendar UI

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

I have this sample code that I revised from David Walsh implementation, my objective is to disable button for the weekends Sat and Sun. I am having some difficulty in implementing it. I hope someone can help me with my problem.`

```
<?php
/*
* Calendar from David Walsh's implementation: http://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar
*/

if(isset($_REQUEST["date"])){

    // Get the variable
    $chosenDate = explode("/",$_REQUEST["date"]);
    $month = $chosenDate[0];
    $year = $chosenDate[1];

    // Check browser
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
        $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }

    /* 
    * Draws the calendar 
    */

    // Draw table 
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    // Table headings 
    $headings = array('S','M','T','W','Th','F','S');
    $calendar.= '<tr><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    // Variables to be used
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $current_date = explode("/",date('m/j/Y')); //Gets the current date 
    $dates_array = array();

    // Row for week one 
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    // Print "blank" days until the first of the current week 
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    // Keep going with days...
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):

        // This checks current day so that past days will never be picked
        if($list_day < $current_date[1] && $month == $current_date[0] && $year == $current_date[2])
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day2">';
        else{
            if(stristr($agent,"firefox")) $value = 'this.textContent';
            else $value = 'innerText';
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day" onclick="redirect_to_sample('.$value.')">';
        }

        // Add in the day number
        if($list_day < $current_date[1] && $month == $current_date[0] && $year == $current_date[2])
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number2">'.$list_day.'</div>';
        else if($list_day == $current_date[1] && $month == $current_date[0] && $year == $current_date[2])
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number"><u>'.$list_day.'</u></div>';
        else 
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';      

        // For further SQLs put here
        $calendar.= str_repeat('<p></p>',2);

        $calendar.= '</td>';

        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    // Finish the rest of the days in the week 
    if($days_in_this_week < 8 && $days_in_this_week != 1):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    // Final row 
    $calendar.= '</tr>';

    // End the table 
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    // All done, return result 
    echo $calendar;
}


   ?>`
```

The class that will disable the sat and sun is <`<td class="calendar-day2">`

Comment: I've already figured it out: just add (|| ($running_day==0 || $running_day==6)) to the if(($list_day < $current_date[1] && $month == $current_date[0] && $year == $current_date[2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$running_day` is keeping track of the Day of the Week. 0 = Saturday & 6 = Sunday so you can leverage this.

Try the following:

```
// This checks current day so that past days will never be picked
if($list_day < $current_date[1] && $month == $current_date[0] && $year == $current_date[2])
      $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day2">';}
elseif($running_day == 0 || $running_day == 6) //Check for weekend
{
     $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day weekend">';    } 
else{
        if(stristr($agent,"firefox")) $value = 'this.textContent';
        else $value = 'innerText';
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day" onclick="redirect_to_sample('.$value.')">';
}
```

I've checked for weekend, created a different `td` tag with an additional css class of weekend so you can add some additional styling for weekends.

Note, I haven't tested this and am taking a bit of a guess.

Comment: it is a possible solution but to make things simpler, just add (|| ($running_day==0 || $running_day==6)) to the if(($list_day < $current_date[1] && $month == $current_date[0] && $year == $current_date[2]).

Comment: @tomjerry, that was my orignal thought, but you *may* want to handle weekends diferntly to past dates. E.g. in addition to styling you could add a title attribute to provide some feedback `title='Please select a weekday'`

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
```

Comment: how can I implement it? All the disabled dates are in this class <td class="calendar-day2">

Comment: The question makes no reference to a `datepicker` jquery plug-in. It is a php implimentation. You should read the question more carefully before answering.

Comment: I've already figured it out: just add (|| ($running_day==0 || $running_day==6)) to the if(($list_day < $current_date[1] && $month == $current_date[0] && $year == $current_date[2])